# How to synchronize Database and DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have been trying to synchronize a database trough a `DataGridView`. So far I have created a data model class. This class contains multiple Properties that match the database. They are mapped using the `[Table]` and `[Column]` attributes from the `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` namespace.

Ok. So I bound the `DataGridView` using the `DataSource`-Property to a `DataContext` connecting to the Database (MSSQL). This Logic is implemented in a **singleton** class, so I can assure there is a single instance of this `DataContext`.

```
 this.m_context = new DataContext(conn);
 this.m_VisitorTable = m_context.GetTable<Visitor>();
```

Well, if I bind the table to my `DataGridView.DataSource` I can see all my entries from the database loaded and shown correctly. Then if I change something I found myself confronted with the synchronization problem. The changed cell did not change on the database side.

To save the changes I implemented this method:

```
public void SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
       // I have no idea what I'm doing here.
       VisitorLogic.Instance.m_VisitorTable.Context.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.Con
       // I'm also trying to see if changes were made so I can save them before closing.
       this.m_bChangesMade = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to save.", "Error");
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to make the whole synchronizing to the database happen automatically? Like autocommit on change. I guess I will have to change something on the model Class. Right now, it does not implement any interfaces nor inherit anything.

This is the class declaration:

```
[Table(Name = "tblVisitor")]
public class Visitor
```

Further on, I have not found a way to update my `DataGridView` "correctly". This is how I make it now, but it seems it's not always working. Is there a better way to do this?

```
// Retrieve the new data from the database
VisitorLogic.Instance.m_VisitorTable.Context.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, VisitorLogic.Instance.m_VisitorTable);


// Set the DataSource to 'null'
this.dataGridView.DataSource = null;

// Refresh (?!)
this.dataGridView.Refresh();

// Bind the new DataSource, hoping it will show the new data.
this.dataGridView.DataSource = VisitorLogic.Instance.m_VisitorTable;
this.m_bChangesMade = false;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the BindingSource object. This will keep your DataTable synchronized with the DataGridView.

So set the DataSource of the BindingSource to the table, then set the DataSource of the DataGridView to the BindingSource.

Example:

```
// DataGridView
DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();

// BindingSource (used for synchronizing table and grid)
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

// Set DataSource of BindingSource to table
bs.DataSource = table;

// Set grid DataSource
dg.DataSource = bs;
```

To update the underlying database you would usually call

```
bindingsource.EndEdit();
dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
```

[**Here's a tutorial and a bit more in-depth info about the binding source object:**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

[**Saving Data from Application to Database (msdn):**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171932%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[**Data Binding using LINQ to SQL in C#**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/dbinDlinq07022007080049AM/dbinDlinq.aspx)

Comment: Ok, so I wasn't so wrong with one of my trys. But where do I commit changes on the DataGridView now? Do I do this with the bindingSource also?


PS:The corporate firewall has got your posted link blocked.

Comment: Yes. You basically work on the bindingsource. As the name suggests, this object binds the data of the database to the control (in this case datagridview).

Comment: I can't find any method from the bindingSource allowing me to commit changes. Maybe I'm blind...

Comment: You would call dataAdapter.Update(dataTable) to update the underlying database.

To be exact:
bindingsource.EndEdit();
dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);


Here's a tutorial and a bit more in-depth info about the binding source object: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Comment: OK. As I'm using `System.Data.Linq` as OOR namespace, I had to do it a bit different, and I'm still not satisfied with how it works.

To save it, I use the `Linq.Table<Visitor>.Context.SubmitChanges()` method.
To refresh my view, I use `Linq.Table<Visitor>.Context.Refresh()` and then I do a `ResetBindings(false)` with the BindingSource. This updates the BindingSource and the DataGridView.

Comment: Maybe this could help you a bit to optimize your solution:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/dbinDlinq07022007080049AM/dbinDlinq.aspx

It takes Linq into consideration and shows techniques of working with the bound database.