# Error "Rows cannot be programatically added to datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and few `TextBox` and combo box controls. when i enter data in textbox controls and click on add button the values are added to `DataGridView`view for user view and on clicking save button the values gets saved in DB.

The problem is that I have a `TextBox`(Invoice_No), On this `TextBox`leave event i have written code to fetch data from DB to data grid view. Now i am not able to add additional row to this grid by entering values in `TextBox`controls. It gives the below error

> Rows cannot be programatically added to datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myconnectionstring);

    string getinvdtlcnt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoice_detail WHERE invoice_no = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getinvdtlcnt, connection);
    connection.Open();
    var ObjResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int Result = Convert.ToInt32(ObjResult);
    connection.Close();
    if (Result > 0)
    {                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            string getinvdtl = "SELECT invoice_no Invoice_No,invoice_line_no Invoice_Line_No,barcode Barcode,product_name Product_Name,description Description,vendor_name Vendor_Name,unit_qty Unit_Qty,UOM,total_qty Total_Qty,single_qty_cost Single_Qty_Cost,single_qty_retail Single_Qty_Retail,cost Cost,retail Retail,discount Discount,amount Amount FROM invoice_detail WHERE invoice_no = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(getinvdtl, connection);

            MySqlCommandBuilder cmdbuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            connection.Close();
            int r;
            bool isRvalid = int.TryParse(Result.ToString(),out r);
            textBox2.Text = (Result + 1).ToString();
            textBox3.Focus();
    }
}

private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" | textBox3.Text == "" | textBox4.Text == "" | comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 | textBox5.Text == "" | textBox6.Text == "" | textBox7.Text == "" | textBox8.Text == "" | textBox9.Text == "" | textBox10.Text == "" | textBox11.Text == "" | textBox12.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Values Should not Be empty!");
        textBox3.Focus();
    }
    else
    {                
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, richTextBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, textBox5.Text, comboBox2.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text, textBox12.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add row in your Datasource and then set the datasource to updated datatable.
Like:

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" | textBox3.Text == "" | textBox4.Text == ""  comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 | textBox5.Text == "" | textBox6.Text == "" | textBox7.Text == "" | textBox8.Text == "" | textBox9.Text == "" | textBox10.Text == "" | textBox11.Text == "" | textBox12.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Values Should not Be empty!");
        textBox3.Focus();
    }
    else
    {      
        DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;  
        dt.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, richTextBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, textBox5.Text, comboBox2.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text, textBox12.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `DataGridView` is bound to a data using the `DataSource` property, you cannot add new rows to the `DataGridView` directly. This is an expected error and documented in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbs04kbx(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `DataGridView` control itself allows to you to add new rows if `AllowUserToAddRows` the property is set to true.

If you still want to use the text boxes to get input and add to the `DataGridView` you have to manipulate the underlying `DataTable` which you have set as `DataSource`.

**Untested sample code**

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" | textBox3.Text == "" | textBox4.Text == "" | comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 | textBox5.Text == "" | textBox6.Text == "" | textBox7.Text == "" | textBox8.Text == "" | textBox9.Text == "" | textBox10.Text == "" | textBox11.Text == "" | textBox12.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Values Should not Be empty!");
        textBox3.Focus();
    }
    else
    {                
        DataTable dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
        if(dt != null)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            // set the field values as required                
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, richTextBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, textBox5.Text, comboBox2.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text, textBox12.Text);
        }            
    }
}
```

If you want to synchronize the `DataGridView` and the `DataBase` use the `BindingSource`. Check the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284548/how-to-synchronize-database-and-datagridview) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Juniath. It did not add row at first but when i changed the line dt.Rows.Add(row) as dt.rows.add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, richTextBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, textBox5.Text, comboBox2.Text, textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text, textBox8.Text, textBox9.Text, textBox10.Text, textBox11.Text, textBox12.Text);