# entity framework 6 datagridview nested child databind

Tags: c#, datagridview, nested, entity-framework-6

I'm running on a dead end trying to save edited data in a datagridview using EF6 and nested child objects. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction..

I have 2 entities:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
}

public class Function
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Property { get; set}
}
```

Next I want to show Customer and the child object from function in a datagridview like so: 
Id .. Name .. Function.Property

Datagridview is customized by disabling AutoGenerateColumns. DataPropertyName is set to the objects below:

I created a ModelView:

```
public class CustomerModelViewObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }            
    public int f_prop { get; set; } /* Function.Property */
}
```

So far, so good. I can see the items and I can edit them. When clicking on the 'save' button I need the changes to reflect to the database, but I can't get it to work. I've been looking and searching for 2 days now, but to no avail.

Query and datasource:

```
var q = from it in _context.KlantenConfigs
select new CustomerModelViewObject
{
    Id = it.Id,                        
    Name= it.Name,
    f_prop= it.Function.Property                      
};

klantenConfigDataView.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

I really hope someone can help me with this. I will be grateful for ever! :-)

Answer (score 0):

To save, you need to (after your save event) get the updated values from the datagridview, update the related entities in `_context.KlantenConfigs` and then call `_context.SaveChanges()`

For an easy way to do so see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284808/3997704

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. What do you mean by 'after your save event'? Do you mean that I have to check every row and property to see if it's changed and then map with the related entity? I'm not sure how to accomplish this. How would you get the updated values?

Comment: I found an answer on SO that helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21284808/3997704

Comment: Ok, so I tried to add a bindingsource in between:
BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
my query q
src.DataSource = q.ToList();
klantenConfigDataView.DataSource = src;

It now shows an extra empty line on my datagridview, which is good. I hadn't have it before. But upon calling _context.savechanges(); nothing happens. In SQL profiler I don't see anything moving. The context doesn't see anything changed.. I must be missing something.