# After setting DataSource of DataGridView, Columns and Rows are still empty

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataTable and a DataGridView.

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21284808/258462) but I do not have a DataAdapter so I cannot call `dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);`. I also read some pages of the official documentation (such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)) but I do not comprehend.

Simplified code:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

var c1 = new DataColumn("ColumnA", typeof(int))
{
    Caption = "ColumnA"
};

var c2 = new DataColumn("ColumnB", typeof(int))
{
    Caption = "ColumnB"
};

dt.Columns.Add(c1);
dt.Columns.Add(c2);

var dgv = new DataGridView();

var c11 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "ColumnA",
    DataPropertyName = "ColumnA"
};

var c21 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    Name = "ColumnB",
    DataPropertyName = "ColumnB"
};

dgv.Columns.Add(c11);
dgv.Columns.Add(c21);

var bs = new BindingSource();

// I also tried inverting these two lines:
bs.DataSource = dt;
dgv.DataSource = bs;

dt.Rows.Add(100, 100);
dt.Rows.Add(200, 200);

// I also tried putting this line here:
//bs.EndEdit();

// here bs.Count == 2, but dgv.RowCount == 0
```

Comment: If you add  `this.Controls.Add(dgv);` it works as expected. Not sure why this is needed though.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Thank you. It Works.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek The reason is because *The `BindingContext` of the `DataGridView` before adding to a container control is null and when setting up `DataSource` for the control it checks if the `BindingContext` is null, it doesn't add columns and rows, until after its `BindingContext` changes to a non-null value.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BindingContext` of the `DataGridView` before adding to a container control is null and when setting up `DataSource` for the control it checks if the `BindingContext` is null, it doesn't add columns and rows, until after its `BindingContext` changes to a non-null value.

If it's a control which you are going to add to a parent, then by adding it the the parent you will have columns and rows:

```
this.Controls.Add(dgv);
```

If it's not going to be added to a container and it's for example just for printing purpose, you can set `BindingContext` for the control:

```
dgv.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```