# How can I update a DataSet when editing an Access table directly?

Tags: c#, database, dataset

I am having some problems with a school project that I am doing.

We are supposed to make an Access database and connect it to our C# program using a DataSet as the data source.

The DataSets display perfectly fine when I run it, but when I open up Access and add some new values, the DataSet doesn't update. Visual studio reads the database and the updates just fine when I run an SQL query, but the DataSet doesn't update.

Now, it is HIGHLY probable that I am misunderstanding some crucial aspect of how DataSets work in Visual Studio, but that's why I'm here.

Screenshots and code:

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Database2DataSet ds;
        Database2DataSetTableAdapters.ProizvodTableAdapter prAdapter;
        Database2DataSetTableAdapters.KategorijaTableAdapter krAdapter;
        Database2DataSetTableAdapters.RacunTableAdapter rAdapter;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ds = new Database2DataSet();
            prAdapter = new Database2DataSetTableAdapters.ProizvodTableAdapter();
            krAdapter = new Database2DataSetTableAdapters.KategorijaTableAdapter();
            rAdapter = new Database2DataSetTableAdapters.RacunTableAdapter();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            prAdapter.Fill(ds.Proizvod);
            krAdapter.Fill(ds.Kategorija);
            rAdapter.Fill(ds.Racun);
            proizvodDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Proizvod;
            kategorijaDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Kategorija;

        }
    }
}
```

[image: Top window: The Access Database, bottom window: the form]

Comment: Where is a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) ? [Using the BindingSource Class in ADO.NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/using-bindingsource-class-in-ado-net/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to synchronize Database and DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284548/how-to-synchronize-database-and-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after an hour of tinkering, I realized that the sleep deprivation got to me.

Turns out that I never even used the updated database. I saved a database to a new location and used the old connection string when connecting the DataSet with the database.

It all works now, and I will take some time to read the suggestions that were left here.